# Flutter Dismissible widget with confirmDismiss and showAlertDialog stop app

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

When I try to use confirmDismiss on Dismissible widget with showAlertDialog, it pops up alert but, also throws exception and stop app. If I try to continue after exception, it works normal.

[Maybe similar to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56166236/12208004) 
I've tried showAlertDialog to separate function and different type of calling navigation, but non of them solve it.

```
            Dismissible(
              confirmDismiss: (direction) {
                return showDialog(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (context) {
                    return CupertinoAlertDialog(
                      title: Text('Delete'),
                      content: Text('Delete'),
                      actions: <Widget>[
                        FlatButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            // Navigator.pop(context, false);
                            Navigator.of(
                              context,
                              // rootNavigator: true,
                            ).pop(false);
                          },
                          child: Text('No'),
                        ),
                        FlatButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            // Navigator.pop(context, true);
                            Navigator.of(
                              context,
                              // rootNavigator: true,
                            ).pop(true);
                          },
                          child: Text('Yes'),
                        ),
                      ],
                    );
                  },
                );
              },
              key: Key(UniqueKey().toString()),
              direction: DismissDirection.endToStart,
              onDismissed: (direction) {
                //TODO DELETE
                Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
                  SnackBar(
                    backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                    content: Text(
                      'test',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20.0,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
              background: Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0),
                // alignment: AlignmentDirectional.centerEnd,
                alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.delete,
                  size: 32.0,
                  color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                ),
              ),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
                child: CartCard(),
              ),
            ),
```

this is exception

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: 'package:flutter/src/animation/animation_controller.dart': Failed assertion: line 484 pos 7: '_ticker != null': AnimationController.reverse() called after AnimationController.dispose()
AnimationController methods should not be used after calling dispose.
#0      _AssertionError._doThrowNew  (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:40:39)
#1      _AssertionError._throwNew  (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:36:5)
#2      AnimationController.reverse 
package:flutter/…/animation/animation_controller.dart:484
#3      _DismissibleState._handleDismissStatusChanged 
package:flutter/…/widgets/dismissible.dart:449
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      AnimationLocalStatusListenersMixin.notifyStatusListeners 
package:flutter/…/animation/listener_helpers.dart:193
#5      AnimationController._checkStatusChanged 
package:flutter/…/animation/animation_controller.dart:753
#6      AnimationController._tick (package:flutter/src/animation/animation_contr<…>
```

Comment: I didn't confirm with the same code yet, but this is related to `CupertinoTabView`, and using `key: ValueKey(yourItem),`  could be solve this problem. I got from [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/46766#issuecomment-565629675)

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is not with the dismiss or confirm dismiss method. The error warning is clear: Your issue is with the Animation Controller.

Apparently, somewhere in your code, you are disposing of it - most likely in the:

```
 @override dispose
```

Try to remove it and see if it works.

OK try this

```
        Dismissible(
          confirmDismiss: (direction) {
            return showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (context) {
                return CupertinoAlertDialog(
                  title: Text('Delete'),
                  content: Text('Delete'),
                  actions: <Widget>[
                    FlatButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        // Navigator.pop(context, false);
                        Navigator.of(
                          context,
                          // rootNavigator: true,
                        ).pop(false);
                      },
                      child: Text('No'),
                    ),
                    FlatButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        // Navigator.pop(context, true);
                        Navigator.of(
                          context,
                          // rootNavigator: true,
                        ).pop(true);
                      },
                      child: Text('Yes'),
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              },
            );
          },
          key: UniqueKey(),
          direction: DismissDirection.endToStart,
          onDismissed: (direction) {
            //TODO DELETE
            Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
              SnackBar(
                backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                content: Text(
                  'test',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20.0,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
          background: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0),
            // alignment: AlignmentDirectional.centerEnd,
            alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
            color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
            child: Icon(
              Icons.delete,
              size: 32.0,
              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            ),
          ),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
            child: CartCard(),
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I did't use any dispose method. I'm not sure but, I think this animation controller is connected to dismiss widget, and not my own animation

Comment: I update my comment, but you agree that you have an animation controller somewhere in there?? right?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but it doesn't work. Sorry my explanation was bad, I mean dismiss widget itself contains the animation controller, but I did not add any additional controller.

Comment: I don't see any reference to an animation controller in this dismiss routine. Have you pasted everything?

Comment: I did it. DismissibleState contains an animation controller to control dismiss gesture and its animation.

Answer (score 1):

all you need to do is write a function for example

```
Future<bool> sample(DismissDirection direction) async{
   #write you code
   return true or false;
}
```

it's work for me